# python ipv6 packet sniffer

Tags: python, sockets, ipv6, freebsd, raw-sockets

hi i want to sniff packets via python, ipv6 on FREEBSD.

i hard to trying googlings to get information but there is nothing for freebsd example.

below code is not working because someone says that bsd system does not supporting

socket.PF_PACKET.

Does anyone have any links to Help me?

```
s = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(3))
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, IN.SO_BINDTODEVICE, struct.pack("%ds"%(len("em1")+1,),"em1"))
while condition:
    pkt = s.recvfrom(1500)
    addToQueue(filter(pkt))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at using a Python wrapper for [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/). libpcap is a C library that is used to sniff packets and process `pcap` dumps. This is the same library that [Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/libpcap) uses. It comes standard with OSX and can be installed on most Linux distributions.

There exists a number of Python wrapper for this:

- http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net/
- http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/

Make sure to avoid any implementations that are pure Python, as they are not able to do packet sniffing.